# How to limit error display to certain users or IPs

Tags: xdebug, xdebug-3, xdebug-profiler

Currently when there is a notice or warning, it is displayed on our web pages.
We would like this to be available only to some IPs or other criteria for our developers

Is there a way to render the error log stack only to certain IP?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add a bit more context? I don't understand what you're trying to ask here.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. xdebug displays a formatted error div on the pages. We would like these to only be displayed to users that call the page from certain IPs. Our developers IP.

Answer (score 0):

There is no feature in Xdebug that can do this.

What I would suggest to do is to create two web server vhost configurations, or php-fpm pools, if you're using that. With one configured to have Xdebug on, and the other to have it not activated and loaded. You can then use configuration in your web server to redirect incoming requests to either one of these PHP configurations, depending on the source IP address.